# How can I turn off Skype notifications to others when I go online?

Tags: skype, notifications

How can I turn off Skype's notification of "is online", which is visible to other online members when log in?

Is it possible to do that at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would prefer to hide your presence status completely, you can change this in your profile settings to make yourself invisible.

Tap your **profile picture** > Tap the **Settings** button > Tap **Privacy** > then you can toggle **Show my presence to others** on or off.

EDIT: The above setting no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can control only your notifications.

A way to avoid being displayed as "online" by others is to get in skype "invisble" or stay in skype constantly with a status of your choice.